# Singleton class call gives null pointer exception to main class

Tags: java

So I had a question on here the other day about how to accessing the same data class with two different other classes without creating separate instances.  It was recommended to use a singleton so i have done some research but there isn't a lot about it.

The issue I'm having is that my main class gets a null pointer exception when trying to access the data singleton.  But my other class can access it and get the data just fine.  How exactly is that possible?  I have a pretty basic setup...

singleton

```
public enum laneData {
    INSTANCE;
    private String laneID;

    public String getLaneID() {
        return laneID;
    }

    public void setLaneID(String laneID) {
        this.laneID = laneID;
    }

}
```

main class call

```
 private laneData laneData;
 public void init() {
     laneData.setLaneID("test"); //these two lines each throw null pointer unless commented out
     System.out.println(laneData.getLaneID()); 
     ....
```

other class

```
public class XMLParser {
private LaneGUI laneGUI;
private laneData laneData;


public void parseInputString(String input){ 
laneData.setLaneID(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));  //both of these work fine
System.out.println("stored ID: " + laneData.getLaneID());
```

Comment: It's been a while since I used Java. Is it common now to use `enum` to implement a Singleton pattern in Java? It smells to me like retrofitting a construct that it was not originally designed for.

Comment: It is the suggested way to do it now @Santa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `private laneData laneData = laneData.INSTANCE;`.

You can also just use `laneData.INSTANCE.getLaneID()`.

Java guidelines also recommend than Class and Enum names be capitalized, I.E. `LaneData`.

Comment: In the main, the other class, or both? And if so, why does the access work in one class but not the other? And I just tried it.. it gives an error stating self-reference in initializer

Comment: In both. In your second case where it works, you are probably initializing the laneData instance variable in your constructor or some other place.

Answer (score 2):

> It was recommended to use a singleton
>   so i have done some research but there
>   isn't a lot about it.

There is a lot out there about the singleton pattern.

This is an example singleton (note the differences)

```
public class MySingleton {
    private String label;
    private static MySingleton single;
    private MySingleton(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance(String label) {
        if (singleton == null) singleton = new MySingleton(label);
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not thread safe, and it is actually recommended to do it like @Jesse is doing it.

Comment: I did read a "decent" amount of info.  Your example is based on an older version of java.  Apparently with java 6 you can just enum the type and it has the same effect.  except it null pointers and i couldn't find anything about that.

Comment: `synchronized` keyword to the rescue?

Comment: this example is not thread safe. As of Java 5, using Enum for singletons is the preferred way to avoid issues with Serialization, etc.

Comment: @Santa, even with proper synchronization, you have to deal with (de)serialization issues.